# Why isn't my if statement executing its print statement Python 2.7.11

Tags: python, python-2.7, if-statement, printing, while-loop

I have a `main` method in Python 2.7.11 that (after its first execution) will ask if the user wants to continue `(y/n)`. The response of `'y'` re-executes the while loop I instantiated in `main` just fine, and erroneous inputs are taken into account and the question is re-asked. However, when the user enters `'n'`, it does not print `'Goodbye.'`, it instead exits out of the loop without even reaching the `print` statement. Here is my code:

```
def main():

    will_continue = 'y' # Default for the first execution

    while will_continue == 'y':
        # A bunch of execution code here for the program...

        # After executing rest of code
        will_continue = raw_input('Do you wish to continue? (y/n): ')

        while will_continue != 'y' and will_continue != 'n':
            if will_continue == 'n':
                print 'Goodbye.'
            else:
                will_continue = raw_input('Invalid input. Do you wish to continue? (y/n): ')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I thought maybe my issue was `and` in `while continue != 'y' and continue != 'n':`, so I changed it to `while continue != 'y' or continue != 'n':`, but this keeps me in an infinite loop of `'Goodbye'` being printed if I input `'n'`, or infinite unresponsiveness if I input `'y'`.

Any ideas as to why that `print 'Goodbye.'` statement won't execute before terminating the `main`?

Comment: where do you define the var `will_continue`?

Comment: and `continue` is a python reserved keyword. you cannot use it as a var name.

Comment: @WreckeR Are you sure? I seem to remember that i have on occasion unknowingly overwritten reserved keywords.

Comment: Python 2.7 won't let me execute a script with `continue` as a variable name. Its possible older version of python allow you to use reserved keywords.

Comment: Okay. I fixed it back to the original.

Comment: Why is this question downvoted? It is a legitimate question, properly asked, and properly formatted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're asking the user for input in the `else` block. If the user inputted 'n', the `while` block will terminate in the next iteration, causing your `if will_continue == 'n'` to never execute. A quick fix for it would be to place your `if` block *outside* of the inner `while` loop.

Alternatively, you can eschew the `if` block and simply have the program print 'Goodbye' at the end regardless of what happens.

Comment: Ah! That did it! Thank you so much, logical error on my part.

Answer (score 0):

will_continue is never changed in your code above, so it will never be 'n'.

Comment: It is changed every time at the end of the while loop, as `continue` is redefined as a new `raw_input`

Comment: @Jodo1992 Actually, it isn't. You're changing `continue`, not `will_continue`.

Comment: I edited the code. `will_continue` is now `continue` for space-saving purposes.

Comment: @Jodo1992 you missed one, which introduces new problems into your question.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an updated version of your code that works.

```
def main():

    con = 'y' # Default for the first execution

    while con == 'y':
        # A bunch of execution code here for the program...

        # After executing rest of code
        con = raw_input('Do you wish to continue? (y/n): ')
        while con != 'y' and con != 'n':
            con = raw_input('Invalid Input. Type y/n: ')
        if con == 'n':
            print 'Goodbye.'


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```